# BYOD - AD Authentication Issues

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am a guy who brings his "own rig" to work. In this new gig I have to run some apps as a domain user provided.

I shift + "right click" -> run as a different user and insert the domain credentials, but this fails.  If I sit on a colleague's machine (which is a member of the domain), authentication works, but on mine, it doesn't.

This application needs to run as a domain user, because it copies files from the network.

Comment: Is your machine connected to the domain (same as your colleagues) or a standalone device?  In terms of "fail", what do you mean here?  Do you receive any errors (credentials incorrect, anything else)?  Does the same issue occur with any domain credentials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your computer is not a domain member, so domain users have no permissions or access to your computer.  The solution, of course, is to join your computer to the domain so that domain users (like your domain user) actually have permissions.

Comment: The reason for this is that when you try and authenticate, your computer will try and validate the credentials. But as it is not a part of the domain it can't find anyone to validate the credentials. And even if it did the Domain Controller has no reason to trust your computer. And as such will not validate any credentials it sends. (Not sure if this is the proper place / use of a comment)

Answer (score 1):

Try running the app using the runas.exe CLI tool, specifying the `/netonly` switch. This will run the app as your local account, but use the creds you provided to runas.exe when accessing network resources.